# Capybara can't find selector on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, capybara

I'm trying to test the presence of some form fields in the bootstrap navbar and can't find the right combination of Capybara selectors to find them.

I've tried the following options in Capybara:

```
  should have_selector('id', text: 'email')
  should have_selector('name', text: 'email')
  should have_selector('div.input.id', text: 'email')
  should have_selector('div.input.placeholder', text: 'email')
```

and I always get the error:

```
       Failure/Error: expect (should have_selector('div.input.placeholder', text: 'email'))
       expected to find visible css "div.input.placeholder" with text "email" but there were no matches
```

I'm fairly new to capybara, which is probably my problem, but I've looked through the documentation and this seems like it should work.

I'm guessing this has something to do with it being hidden, but it is visible to a user when you go to the page, so I'm not sure how to get it to be visible to capybara.

Here is the HTML code that is being presented:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="klUhJ9epE/Sr/N0okPq5WMWi2XJuQXiAPmdg/9Qf2d8TBX+htbIdUPRh01YPWqMTRin8vTlVG/ECUtvKNczc+A==" />
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

Here is the view of the actual page:
[image: form fields in navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div.input.placeholder` is a CSS selector that would select a div element with the classes 'input' and 'placeholder' - I'm assuming that's not what you're actually trying to check for.

If you are trying to test the attribute values you would do

```
have_selector('input[id="email"][placeholder="Email"]')
```

or better yet since you're using CSS

```
have_css('input[id="email"][placeholder="Email"]')
```

or you could use Capybaras built-in :field selector type and do

```
have_field(id: 'email', placeholder: 'Email')
```

Realistically though - checking attributes like this is overkill for a feature test. Just fill in the fields

```
fill_in('Email', with: 'my_email@blah.com')
```

which will confirm the relevant field exists, can be located by label or placeholder of the string 'Email' and can be filled in.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm going to take your suggestion to heart and change it up to just fill in the fields.